# Синтаксическая ошибка не понятно в чем

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

Вот пример процедуры , написанной в MYSQL WORKBENCH версии 8.0. Но уже на строке 3 возникает ошибка "unexpected end of input found , expecting ;" Не могу понять, что не так. Знак ";"  и ставил и убирал.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST()
BEGIN
 DECLARE test_id, last_id, i INT;

SET @TEST_ID = 1 -- start compare with this ID 
SET @LAST_ID = 100 -- end compare with this ID

WHILE @TEST_ID <= @LAST_ID 
 BEGIN 
  SELECT @ID = (SELECT chip_number FROM chip_db WHERE chip_number = @TEST_ID) 
  IF @ID IS NULL 
  BEGIN 
    PRINT 'Missing ID: ' + CAST(@TEST_ID AS VARCHAR(10)) 
  END 
  SET @TEST_ID = @TEST_ID + 1 
 END
END;
```

Comment: Прошу прощения, я не специалист, но может он не одну ; не находит? попробуйте все операторы ею закончить.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Вам нужно переопределить delimeter:

```sql
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE TEST()
BEGIN
DECLARE test_id , last_id, i INT;

SET @TEST_ID = 1; -- start compare with this ID 
SET @LAST_ID = 100; -- end compare with this ID

WHILE @TEST_ID <= @LAST_ID 
 DO 
  SELECT @ID = (SELECT chip_number FROM chip_db WHERE chip_number = @TEST_ID);
  IF @ID IS NULL THEN
  BEGIN 
    SELECT concat('Missing ID: ', @TEST_ID);
  END;
  end if;
  SET @TEST_ID = @TEST_ID + 1;
 END WHILE;
END$$
```

Обратите внимание, насколько я знаю, в mysql print отсутствует, хотя с новыми версиями я не работал, в старых нужно было использовать select.

Comment: Замена PRINT на SELECT  выглядит так ? SELECT @msg + CAST(@TEST_ID AS VARCHAR(10))

Comment: Или без использования дополнительной переменной: select concat('Missing ID: ', 1); У Вашем контексте, наверное, select concat('Missing ID: ',  CAST(@TEST_ID AS VARCHAR(10))); Хотя, мне кажется кастить не нужно, така как concat может принимать числа.

Comment: К сожалению, пока что ваш вариант не сработал. Может я что то не так набрал ((   IF @ID IS NULL THEN
  BEGIN 
    SELECT ('Missing ID: ', CAST(@TEST_ID AS VARCHAR(10)));
  END     Идет ошибка по SELECT select is not valid at this position for this server version

Comment: SELECT concat('Missing ID: ', @TEST_ID); Я исправил свой ответ. Синтаксических ошибок в ньом нет. Это, конечно не означает что это работает.